# What's the difference between index and internal ID in neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm setting up my database and sometimes I'll need to use an ID. At first, I added an ID as a property to my nodes of interest but realized I could also just use neo4j's internal id "". Then I stumbled upon the CREATE INDEX ON :label(something) and was wondering exactly what this would do? I thought an index and the  would be the same thing?

This might be a stupid question, but since I'm kind of a beginner in databases, I may be missing some of these concepts.

Also, I've been reading about which kind of database to use (mySQL, MongoDB or neo4j) and decided on neo4j since my data pretty much follows a graph structure. (it will be used to build metabolic models: connections genes->proteins->reactions->compounds)

In SQL the syntax just seemed too complex as I had to go around several tables to make simple connections that neo4j accomplishes quite easily...
From what I understand MongoDb stores data independently, and, since my data is connected, it doesnt really seem to fit the data structure. 
But again, since my knowledge on this subject is limited, perhaps I'm not doing the right choice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graph dbs are ideal for connected data like this, it's a more natural fit for both storing and querying than relational dbs or document stores.

As far as indexes and ids, here's the [index section](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/) of the docs, but the gist of it is that this has to do with how Neo4j can look up starting nodes. Neo4j only uses indexes for finding these starting nodes (though in 3.5 when we do index lookup like this, if you have ORDER BY on the indexed property, it will use the index to augment the performance of the ordering).

Here is what Neo4j will attempt to use, depending on availability, from fastest to slowest:

1. Lookup by internal ID - This is always quick, however we don't recommend preserving these internal ids outside the context of a query. The reason for that is that when graph elements are deleted, their ids become eligible for reuse. If you preserve the internal ids outside of Neo4j, and perform a lookup with them later, there is a chance that whatever you expected it to reference could have been deleted, and may point at nothing, or may point at some new node with completely different data.
2. Lookup by index - This where you would want to use CREATE INDEX ON (or add a unique constraint, if that makes sense for your model). When you use a MATCH or MERGE using the label and property (or properties) associated with the index, then this is a fast and direct lookup of the node(s) you want.
3. Lookup by label scan - If you perform a MATCH with a label present in the pattern, but no means to use an index (either no index present for the label/property combination, or only a label is present but no property), then a label scan will be performed, and every node of the given label will be matched to and filtered. This becomes more expensive as more nodes with those labels are added.
4. All nodes scan - If you do not supply any label in your MATCH pattern, then every node in your db will be scanned and filtered. This is very expensive as your db grows.

You can EXPLAIN or PROFILE a query to see its query plan, which will show you which means of lookup are used to find the starting nodes, and the rest of the operations for executing the query.

Once a starting node or nodes are found, then Neo4j uses relationship traversal and filtering to expand and find all paths matching your desired pattern.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. So I'm guessing the optimal way to do it is to lookup by index. I tried adding "CREATE INDEX ON :label(node_type)" at the start of the graphDB session. Since I'm running python it goes like this:
   `add_indexes_command='CREATE INDEX ON :label(node_type)'`
   `self.neo4j_driver.session().run(add_indexes_command)`
But when I examined the node properties (for example node_type="Compound"), nothing was added to it? How can I access the index property to look it up later?

Comment: You should read the linked index documentation. When you create an index, it means that when there exists a node with that label, and a property (that you must set), then it will be automatically indexed, so from that point forward you can lookup the node quickly by its label and property (instead of having to do a node by label scan). It does not add anything new to the node, it just allows fast lookup of the node. For example, you could index :Person(name) and after it's created you can quickly lookup :Person nodes by their name property. But it doesn't add the property to the node for you.